# Changes not visible in Search results after update?commit=true in Apache Solr. I am using Drupal 6 and Apache Solr 1.4.1

Tags: php, apache, solr, drupal-6

My site is indexed. I changed a forum topic from 'Where I am' to 'Who I am'. Before Search returned correct results with "Where I am" But now that I have changed the topic name to "Who I am" it still return "Where I am" in results. Though it is changed. I have updated the indexed by update?commit=true and update?optimize=true which return Success. Still it does not change.
Please Help

Comment: Have you reindexed the topic from Drupal (by re-saving it or however Drupal does it), or did you just change the value in the backend database or somewhere outside of Drupal itself?

Comment: I have saved it in the forum. It is visible when you re-visit that page. Then i run update?commit=true, should that make result visible in the search results now as per my understanding. But it doesn`t. Do i need to re-index it to make it available? If yes, What is the purpose of commit then? Can someone explain please

Comment: It will only make it visible if there has been any documents submitted to Solr. The commit is issued after documents has been added to the index to make them visible. If Drupal is not sending any documents to Solr for indexing, a commit won't do anything.

Comment: How would i know a document is added. Secondly how can i add it. Should i have to add it manually everytime ? Or re-indexing adds the document.

Comment: The whole point is that Drupal should handle that for you, so I'll have to leave that to someone who knows the Solr-integration you're using with Drupal.

Comment: I have figured that it has to be re-indexed in order to appear in search results. That cron will handle. Thank you MatsLindh!!